# Is there any way to accelerate tensorflow mobile on Android?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-android

any ideas is OK,cpu usage,tensorflow settings,image preprocess,etc.BTW,not tf lite,and my model is ssd-mobilenet

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider to switch to TensorFlow Lite? It is the recommended approach to run TensorFlow models on mobile devices. It supports kernels which are optimized for ARM CPU and quantization.

See also Google's blog post for running SSD:
https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/07/accelerated-training-and-inference-with.html